# Incorporating uneven sample sizes into linear mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, unbalanced-classes

I have run an experiment measuring behaviour of individual animals of different Species. Given that the species are all quite different, I standardised my experiments by biomass, but this means that my sample sizes are highly uneven i.e. for some species it took only 1 individual to reach the required biomass, and for others it took 30. As a result, the spread of my data is greater for species with considerably more ‘replicates’, and the number of individuals has a significant effect on the variance of behaviour recorded for these species.

As such, I am wanting to account for the Abundance of individuals in my model, where I am looking to whether Behaviour differs between Species. I am hesitant to use a rarefaction-type method to match the lowest sample abundance for all groups, as this would be throwing away a substantial amount of data of the smaller species, and would rather try and weigh the models accordingly, or otherwise acknowledge the role that the sample size is playing.

One thought I had for this would be to use lme4 in R, using Abundance as a continuous predictor to get a slope. I could then use (Abundance|Species) in my model formulae, giving me a (random) slope, i.e. effect of Abundance, for each level of Species.

Do you believe this approach would be viable, or am I wildly off base? Thank you.

Comment: Can you say more about what the outcome variable is? What exactly do you mean by "I standardised my experiments by biomass"?

Comment: It's a unit of time, the seconds taken for each individual to complete a set task (which I've just termed 'Behaviour' here). And the problem has arisen because in each experimental tank, best practise is to keep the overall volume of weight of animals the same. So there were 5g worth of animals in each tank - this is no problem for most of my measures, but as for this one I am interested in an outcome variable were I have a record for each individual, this means my factors are unbalanced (5g worth of one species is 30 animals, but only 6 animals for a bigger species).

Comment: I think you should have a look at a Gamma GLMM. To take into account the differences in biomass the best approach is probably to include an offset for that variable. Concerning the unequal number of individuals, this is taken into account by the random effects.